# Symfony container traits

Tags: php, symfony, containers, traits

Strange problem, 
I have controller which uses **\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait**

```
class MainController
{
    use \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_index")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
         var_dump($this->container);

         return array();
    }
}
```

but result is NULL.

Tried on:

- Symfony 2.5.*
- MAMP 3.0
- PHP 5.4 5.5

My searches have not helped me. I think the solution is easy.

Any ideas how to trace this error?

**UPD:** When i extend from Controller, container is available and everything is working properly. But according to symfony Controller reference extending is optional, i can use traits instead.

Comment: Whether you set the container, before check it?

Comment: I did not set the container, symfony do it. When i extend from Controller, container is available. But according to symfony Controller reference extending Controller is optional, i can use traits instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll venture a guess based on a quick glance into the Symfony source code: You still need to declare that you adhere to the `ContainerAwareInterface` Interface.

This is what the code looks like whenever Symfony is setting a container on a controller.

```
if ($controller instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
  $controller->setContainer($this->container);
}
```

So then I suppose you need to do something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
// ...
class MainController implements ContainerAwareInterface 
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_index")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
         var_dump($this->container);

         return array();
    }
```

}

As an aside, this is arguably a pretty good case for [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), particularly if they had named the method something a bit more specific or if it were cheaper to inspect the parameter types to methods at runtime

Comment: Thank you, you save me a lots of hours.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your proposal for Duck Typing a little further? I afraid don't get it.

Comment: @flu The Symfony authors might've  (instead of using `instanceof`) checked if your controller had a `setContainer` method. In some programming languages, this is called "informal protocol", or more casually, "Duck Typing" (If it quacks like a duck, assume it can be handled like a duck). PHP may not be the best language for this, but I like to connect ideas across platform lines where possible on SO. The reason I say it may not be best is that you would generally want to check not just that there is a `setContainer` method, but also that it takes the correct type of thing as it's parameter.