# Symfony - FOSUserBundle Profile view does not work after update to Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

I have upgraded my Symfony project from version 2.6 to 2.8 and after that, I receive an error 500 when I request the profile view. The error is:

```
Error: Call to a member function has() on null

Stack Trace in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 350   -
 */
public function getUser()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application.');
    }
```

When I run composer show -i, I see the next list:

```
You are using the deprecated option "installed". Only installed packages are shown by default now. The --all option can be used to show all packages.
doctrine/annotations                 v1.4.0             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.6.2             Caching library offering a...
doctrine/collections                 v1.4.0             Collections Abstraction li...
doctrine/common                      v2.7.3             Common Library for Doctrin...
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.13            Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.8.1              Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.3.2              Symfony Bundle for Doctrin...
doctrine/inflector                   v1.1.0             Common String Manipulation...
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5              A small, lightweight utili...
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1             Base library for a lexer t...
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.14            Object-Relational-Mapper f...
friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle    1.5.3              A pretty nice way to expos...
friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle 1.5.0              Symfony2 OAuth Server Bundle
friendsofsymfony/oauth2-php          1.2.2              OAuth2 library
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle         dev-master 9b3be01 Symfony FOSUserBundle
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler v2.1.2             Composer script handling y...
ircmaxell/password-compat            v1.0.4             A compatibility library fo...
jdorn/sql-formatter                  v1.2.17            a PHP SQL highlighting lib...
jms/aop-bundle                       1.3.0              Adds AOP capabilities to S...
jms/cg                               1.2.0              Toolset for generating PHP...
jms/di-extra-bundle                  1.9.1              Allows to configure depend...
jms/metadata                         1.6.0              Class/method/property meta...
jms/parser-lib                       1.0.0              A library for easily creat...
jms/security-extra-bundle            dev-master c4a5dda Enhances the Symfony2 Secu...
knplabs/knp-snappy                   v1.0.4             PHP5 library allowing thum...
knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle            v1.5               Easily create PDF and imag...
kriswallsmith/assetic                v1.4.0             Asset Management for PHP
liuggio/ExcelBundle                  v2.1.0             This is a Symfony2 Bundle ...
monolog/monolog                      1.23.0             Sends your logs to files, ...
paragonie/random_compat              v2.0.11            PHP 5.x polyfill for rando...
phpoffice/phpexcel                   1.8.1              PHPExcel - OpenXML - Read,...
phpoption/phpoption                  1.5.0              Option Type for PHP
phpunit/php-code-coverage            1.2.18             Library that provides coll...
phpunit/php-file-iterator            1.4.5              FilterIterator implementat...
phpunit/php-text-template            1.2.1              Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                    1.0.9              Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream             1.2.2              Wrapper around PHP's token...
phpunit/phpunit                      3.7.38             The PHP Unit Testing frame...
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects         1.2.3              Mock Object library for PH...
psr/log                              1.0.2              Common interface for loggi...
sensio/distribution-bundle           v2.3.22            The base bundle for the Sy...
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v3.0.29            This bundle provides a way...
sensio/generator-bundle              v2.5.3             This bundle generates code...
stripe/stripe-php                    v3.23.0            Stripe PHP Library
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v5.4.9             Swiftmailer, free feature-...
symfony/assetic-bundle               v2.8.2             Integrates Assetic into Sy...
symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.12.1            Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu            v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill for intl'...
symfony/polyfill-mbstring            v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill for the M...
symfony/polyfill-php54               v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill backporti...
symfony/polyfill-php55               v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill backporti...
symfony/polyfill-php56               v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill backporti...
symfony/polyfill-php70               v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill backporti...
symfony/polyfill-util                v1.7.0             Symfony utilities for port...
symfony/security-acl                 v2.8.0             Symfony Security Component...
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.6.7             Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                      v2.8.0             The Symfony PHP framework
twig/extensions                      v1.5.1             Common additional features...
twig/twig                            v1.35.0            Twig, the flexible, fast, ...
willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator  v1.1.0             JSONP callback validator.
```

I have been researching for hours and I haven´t found useful information about this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the dev-master of the user bundle which is no longer compatible with 2.8.  You need to use one of the 2.x tagged versions but I'm not sure which one.  The error by the way comes from the fact that the container is no longer being injected into the controller.  Though exactly why it not being injected is unknown to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Cerad. I downgrade the bundle to the 2.0.1 version but the same error appears.

Comment: I suspect it has been a long time since you actually updated dependencies?  I suspect some of your other bundles will need updating as well.  All I can suggest is that you create a fresh 2.8 project and then require each of your dependencies resulting in a new composer.json file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your Controllers. Probably they extend Symfony\Component\ DependencyInjection\ContainerAware that is deprecated since version 2.8. Remove this and use **Symfony\ Component\DependencyInjection\ ContainerAwareTrait**.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

class MyBundleController implements ContainerAwareInterface { 
    use ContainerAwareTrait; 
    /** 
    * @Route("/", name="_index") 
    * @Template() 
    */ 
    public function indexAction() { 
            var_dump($this->container); 
            return array(); 
    }
}
```

Edit: Cerad was right in the comments:

> there is is not need to rewrite your existing controllers that extend from Controller. The problem is in third party bundles like the FOSUserBundle which do not extend from Controller. However, even they should still work under 2.8 or at least give different errors.

It should work in either case.

References:

- [ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25779264)
- [Symfony 2.8 upgrade](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md) -> ContainerAwareTrait

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Certainly, my bundles does not implements that interface. My bundles look like "class MyController extends Controller" where the use statement is "use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;". Would I have to rewrite all my controllers to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to rewrite for one controller that you get the error to see if it resolves. You can keep the extend: class MyBundleController extends Controller implements ContainerAwareInterface {

Comment: @Airam No, there is is not need to rewrite your existing controllers that extend from Controller.  The problem is in third party bundles like the FOSUserBundle which do not extend from Controller.  However, even they should still work under 2.8 or at least give different errors.

Comment: For 2.8 you need it. FOS user bundle controllers just extend main symfony controller without doing this. Symfony v3 main controller uses the Trait, so I guess FOS user bundle is imconpatable with symfony v2.8. Either upgrade to v3.0 or downgrade to v2.7

Comment: @JannesBotis Actually, FOSUserBundle 1.x extends from ContainerAware.  For 2.x they extend from Controller.  However, there are many other reasons why the 1.x stuff will not work on S2.8.  Nor will the 1.x version work in S3.0.  Basically, the op is faced with the issue of upgrading FOSUserBundle from 1.x to 2.x and at the same time dealing with assorted other BC breaks introduced by S2.8.  Not just the FOSUserBundle but many of the other third party bundles as well.  It is a mess.

Comment: Finally, I updated the FOSUserBundle to the 2.0.2 version, limit other bundles versions which were with dev@master. After the bundles were updated and the cache cleaned, my project worked perfectly. Thanks for the comments.